# Reactjs Data Grid Large Data Cut-off react-data-grid

Tags: reactjs, react-data-grid

i started using react-data-grid and i noticed that the row heights aren't adjusting when i have a cell with lots of text. The text just gets cut-off.  how do i solve this?

Example: say i have text that states "this is a test of long data" then it displays like this...

```
|-----------------|
|this is a test of|
|-----------------|
```

Yes, i could make my column wider but in reality i have item descriptions that are 50 words, more or less, that i want to display in a column and so i'd expect the row to be higher and the text to wrap like so...

```
|-----------------|
|this is a test of|
|long data        |
|-----------------|
```